# How to send custom http_headers for RPC calls using python xmlrpclib?

Tags: python, http-headers, xml-rpc, xmlrpclib

How can I send custom `HTTP Headers` using python `xmlrpclib` library ! ?
I need to send some special custom `http_headers` at the time of calling `RPC` methods.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can subclass `xmlrpclib.Transport` and pass that as an argument to `ServerProxy`. Pick a method to override (I chose `send_content`) and you're set.

```
# simple test program (from the XML-RPC specification)
from xmlrpclib import ServerProxy, Transport, Error

class SpecialTransport(Transport):

    def send_content(self, connection, request_body):

        print "Add your headers here!"

        connection.putheader("Content-Type", "text/xml")
        connection.putheader("Content-Length", str(len(request_body)))
        connection.endheaders()
        if request_body:
            connection.send(request_body)


# server = ServerProxy("http://localhost:8000") # local server
server = ServerProxy("http://betty.userland.com", transport=SpecialTransport())

print server

try:
    print server.examples.getStateName(41)
except Error, v:
    print "ERROR", v
```

Comment: I am not able to use this as I am getting an exception af the first method call, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17569519/unable-to-use-custom-transport-class-with-python-xmlrpclib-due-to-typeerror-unb